# Bring back the 'There were build errors' dialog in visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I clicked the "*don't show again*" checkbox by an accident and now I don't know if there are any build errors. It just launches the old build, which is annoying.

How can I make this dialog show again?

[image: the visual studio dialog]

Transcription of image message:

> There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're referring to the setting for:

**On Run, when build or deployment errors occur**

This can be found in `Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\Build and Run`:

[image: screenshot]